# horizontal scroll bar missing from the website

Tags: css, html, overflow

[WEBSITE LINK](http://ijazpervezcompany.com/)

The above link was a responsive site in the start. But due to the nature of the content, had to add a lot of tables etc and now when i zoom in the website on my browser ,it is does not show any horizontal scroll bars and same goes for when i try to view it on my phone.

i tried different ways like adding overflow-x:auto to the body and removing all the overflow: hidden but still am unable to see my whole website enlarged.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and this

```
#art-main {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i did just remove it but its still the same.

Comment: I still see the overflow-x: hidden; on the body tag.

Comment: Thank you so much ! i had been banging my head and i finally searched for body tag in all the style sheets and found it in one of the plugins file i had placed. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that main div (art-main) is containing everything and is defined as:

```
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
```

So if you resize the page, the div is adapting his size to fit the screen, and the content that is outside that size is cutted out.

I think you should work on this.